# How to install Sun Java on Debian?

Tags: java, debian

On current Debian testing, I am unable to install sun-java6 packages. They are not in the repository. Legacy software depends on them, I must install them right now.

Answer (score 4):

Check the following wiki regarding Java installation on Debain:

https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

to install Java Development Kit(jdk)

```
# apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

or the Java runtime environment (jre):

```
# apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun

Comment: Package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. However the following packages replace it: `sun-java6-demo`. I guess I'll have to add squeeze back to my sources.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another resource (for Ubuntu) that includes instructions for manually installing Oracle (aka Sun) Java 6 on Ubuntu.  I think that the instructions should work for Debian too.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

The page also covers other versions of Java.

Comment: I'll check it shortly. Thanks to everyone for your feedback so far.